# Openshift jbossews cartridge connection refused from outside but reachable from localhost

Tags: jboss, openshift, connection-refused

My jbossews cartridge is suddenly no more available through the webbrowser but when logged in via SSH it seems to be reachable:

What I've done so far:

- When I `gear restart` my cartrdige, I get `Found 127.3.72.129:8080 listening port`.
- `wget 127.3.72.129:8080` actually downloads the valid index.html
- With a wget on the external domain `wget test-locked.rhcloud.com` (also with ":8080") I just get `Connection refused`
- Catalina log also gives no hint about any problems. It reports the server to be started up successfully without any warnings.
- access log also shows no request at all coming in.
- disk quota is available, too

I'm running out of ideas what I could check next or get the gear up and running again. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After Openshift having recovered like magically, the answer to such an issue seems to be: "relax, wait and see".